# Shellscript to remove particular tags in HTML file

Tags: shell-script, sed, grep, html

Can anyone please guide me with writing Shell Script command for following scenario.

I have an html file with all tags in a single line like this,

```
<html><head></head><body><br><center><h2 style='display: block;font-size: 1.5em;weight: bold;'>Validation Report</h2></center></body><table style='border:1px solid;border-collapse: separate;border-spacing: 2px;border-color: gray;' align='center'width='85%' cellpadding ='4' cellspacing='1' bgcolor='#CFCFCF' ><tr style='background-color:#a6caf0;height:30px;font-size:12px;'><th style='width:467px;border: 1px solid;'>TestCaseID</th><th style='border: 1px solid;'>Severity</th><th style='width:125px;border: 1px solid;'>Result</th><th style='width:148px;border: 1px solid;'>Remark</th><tr style='background-color:#ebf3fc;' align='center'><td style='width:360px;border: 1px solid;'>TESTCASE-001</td><td style='width:360px;border: 1px solid;'>Critical</td><td style='width:125px;border: 1px solid;'>Error</td><td style='width:125px;border: 1px solid;'>None</td></tr><tr style='background-color:#ebf3fc;' align='center'><td style='width:360px;border: 1px solid;'>TESTCASE-002</td><td style='width:360px;border: 1px solid;'>Critical</td><td style='width:125px;border: 1px solid;'>Error</td><td style='width:125px;border: 1px solid;'>None</td></tr></table></body></html>
```

This file when viewed in a browser, will have a table look with entries of Testcase ID, their corresponding Severity, Result and Remark. This HTML file has totally 210 TestcaseIDs. Now I have to remove particular rows in a table by mentioning their TestcaseID. ( Say, I need to remove a row which has TESTCASE-002 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the tag with **XSL Transformations** (XSLT).

Most distros should come with an `xsltproc` command (part of the `libxslt` package).

Here is the command to perform the transform, which can be used in a shellscript:

`xsltproc --html main.xslt index.html`

And here is the XSLT which will remove *TESTCASE-002*:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="tr[td = 'TESTCASE-002']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The advantage of this approach is that it's declarative, reusable and separates the code that deals with XML/HTML from the rest of the shell script. It's also flexible and powerful. The disadvantage is that it's slightly verbose and cumbersome.

This method can also handle HTML that is not well formed.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works exactly. I never knew about XSL Transformations before. Now I'm learning and using it. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of a text processing tool like sed/grep, use a tool that understands HTML.

For example, in [xsh](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), you can

```
open :F html file.html ;
delete //tr[td='TESTCASE-002'] ;
save :b ;
```

You have to fix the file first, though - remove the misplaced `</body>` and `</head>` endtags.

Comment: Thanks but I'm writing shell script. I'm planning to achieve this through sed and regular expressions.

Comment: @Thiripu xsh is a shell scripting language, but unlike bash it is meant for working with XML (which also covers HTML)

Comment: I'm automating one setup in bash. In between, Will it be efficient to use xsh for this requirement alone? If yes, How would I integrate this in my bash script?

Comment: @Thiripu: You can run xsh from bash, i.e.: `xsh 'open file.html ; delete //...'`

Comment: You can't reliably parse html with regular expressions.  Use an xml parser instead.  There are many to choose from, including `xsh` mentioned here and `xsltproc` mentioned by Alexander.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Thiripu, you integrate it into your bash script in the same way you would an awk or sed or perl script.  it's a scripting tool meant to be used from sh just as they are.

Comment: @Thiripu if you're worried about efficiency, pretty much _anything_ will be more efficient than the shell. So yes, calling an external program to do the processing from within your shell script is more efficient. See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169765)

Answer (score -1):

This string will pull out the first entry in your html block

```
awk -F"TESTCASE-" '{print $2}' test.html |sed -e 's/<[^>]*>/ /g'
```

And this will pull out the second

```
awk -F"TESTCASE-" '{print $3}' test.html |sed -e 's/<[^>]*>/ /g'
```

If you use the -v option with awk you can pass a bash variable and pull out whichever block you need.

Comment: This command removed all tags in that file. ( Including <head><body> everything )

Comment: @Thiripu: My apologies I misunderstood the question. I took it to mean you wished to have your script return the information for a row from within the block.